# Excel Macro: Action To Selected Word

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get the Macro to do a set order of actions on any word I highlight/Select?

I recorded myself selecting a word, then performing the actions. The idea is to have to actions done to any word I select. However, when I select any other words to perform the Macro, it only does it to "And".

The code:

```
Sub Test()
    '
    ' Test Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+r
    '
    Range("AW2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "And"
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "And"
    Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""And"", RC[-2]:R[4545]C[-2])), ""yes"",   ""no"")"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N4547")
    Range("N2:N4547").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4577
    Range("N4555").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-4553]C:R[-8]C, ""yes"")"
    Range("N4556").Select
End Sub
```

In essence, I want "And" replaced with a variable that means "any word I highlight".

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? VBA will be at halt if you edit a cell. Also you should show the code you have and tell in detail what is not working.

Comment: Check the edit. I want the macro applied to any word I highlight.

Comment: As @DirkReichel said, what do you mean by "highlight"?  Are you in the middle of editing a cell and you "select" one word within the text of that cell (in which case you won't be able to run a macro at that point), or do you simply mean you are selecting a cell which contains a word?

Comment: I want to:
1. Select a cell that contains a string
2. Press the Macro key
3. Have the Macro create new column, name the first row that string, check other boxes to see if it contains that string, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, select the cell with the value you want to use and run this code:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim str As String
  str = Selection.Value
  Columns("N:N").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
  Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = str
  Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""" & str & """, RC[-2]:R[4545]C[-2])), ""yes"",   ""no"")"
  Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N4547")
  Range("N4555").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-4553]C:R[-8]C, ""yes"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I was looking for! So the logic I was looking for was the 'Selection.Value' part, which I couldn't find at all on the web.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to execute VBA code while editing a cell.  You must save or undo changes before VBA will execute.

The best that you can hope for is to copy the value and then either ask for that value in your code, or have VBA examine the clipboard for a valid value.  Doing the latter is complicated and is another question entirely, so I won't elaborate here save to say that there is code available on the net to do just that.

Comment: Thanks! I instead went about making an array inside the VBA, then doing the Macro Actions for every list item.